# an unhandled Microsoft .net framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [5808]

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, w3wp

I'm developing an ASP.NET web app on AWS EC2 Windows Server 2016 and using VS 2019.
Been trying to get this older web app that was on Windows Server 2008 R2 to work on WS 2016, 
and now I'm getting this "ghost" Just-in-time popup.

I've restarted Windows Server a couple times.  And keep getting this pops up -- even if I don't start VS!

[image]

...THE "PROCESS DETAILS" are...
Process Name: w3wp.exe
user Name: IIS APPPOOL\myWeb [Elevated]

Comment: Try to start VS2019 with admin rights

Comment: Once installed, VS becomes a postmortem debugger, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/enabling-postmortem-debugging#specifying-a-postmortem-debugger Whenever an exception happens on your Windows, it will then be called to debug. If you don't like that behavior, unregister it.

Comment: Admin rights did not fix it.

Comment: Thanks, Lex Li.  So I'll try deleting and re-installation the IIS web site.  Maybe that will fix if this is a pool problem.